# Setting up kafka listener in nodejs microservice

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, event-driven

I am wondering about how to proceed with the set up of kafka listener. Should I be running two separate processes `node server.js` and `node kafka-listener.js` for every micro service?

I have some sample code of both of them:

This is `server.js` which runs the node server

```
    require('dotenv').config() // Accesses the environment variables from .env file at the root of the folder or from the docker environment

var port = process.env.PORT;
const express = require("express"),
    createtables = require("./config/createtables.js"),
    vogels = require('vogels'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    logger = require('./config/logger'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser");

createtables();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//We are using a different port for testing because we might want to have the development server ON when we run tests
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    port = 3002
}

app.use(morgan('dev', {
    skip: function (req, res) {
        return res.statusCode < 400
    }, stream: process.stderr
}));

app.use(morgan('dev', {
    skip: function (req, res) {
        return res.statusCode >= 400
    }, stream: process.stdout
}));

var routes = require('./api/routes/LRRoutes');
routes(app);


app.listen(port, function(){
    logger.info('Example app listening on port ' + port);
});

module.exports = app; // for testing
```

This is a sample kafka listener (`kafka-listener.js`):

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
        Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
        client = new kafka.Client(),
        consumer = new Consumer(client,
                    [{ topic: 'name', offset: 0}],
                    {
                                    autoCommit: false
                                }
                );

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
});

consumer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error:',err);
})

consumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', function (err) {
        console.log('offsetOutOfRange:',err);
})
```

Should the listener be run as a separate process? Or is there any other alternative to this?

If you have inputs how routing is done once a there is a message to the listener. Please add that too.

Comment: you can run the kafka listener in the same process as the other application logic, it does not need to run as a separate process. Not sure what you mean by routing but the callback function consumer.on('message') will fire whenever there is incoming messages to your Kafka listener.